# pip install 'what you want to install' isn't working

Tags: python, pip

When I try to do

```
pip install py2exe
```

it says

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  operable program or batch file.
```

I've tried to add C:\Python364\Scripts and C:\Python364\ to my path or environmental settings.

I don't know what to do, I'm on Windows 8.1, Python 3.6.4, If anyone knows whats going wrong it would be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: What happens if you run `python -m pip --version`?

Comment: Try `pip3` and let us know what happens

Comment: for pip3 it said the same thing and when i do python -m pip --version it says python isn't recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 2):

Your python versions is 3.6.4, so you should use `pip3 install py2exe`.

Comment: check your python version first!

Comment: When I open a shell it says Python Version 3.6.4, that might be wrong tho

Comment: I just checked my files, its python 3.6.4

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help